# How to specify my restful API for swagger-ui in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, swagger

I am using spring-boot + jersey as restful implementation. I have setup the swagger and I am able to open the swagger ui on the browser. But the swagger-ui doesn't have any API to show, it is an empty page. Below is the code I setup for configuring swagger. How can I let swagger to scan my API definition in jersey?

**SwaggerConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration  {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/com.hello.*"))
                .build().pathMapping("/swagger2");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("App API")
                .description("App API")
                .version("1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("")
                .contact("Cooltoo company")
                .license("Public")
                .licenseUrl("http://hello.com/")
                .build();
}
```

**JerseyConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Api(value = "home", description = "Demo API")
@ApplicationPath("/nursego")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        register(BadgeAPI.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(OrderAPI.class);
        register(NurseAPI.class);

        configureSwagger();
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/nursego");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.cooltoo.backend.api");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        register( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class );
        register( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class );
    }
}
```

[image]

When I open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, I see below image but none of them are from my API. I don't know where they are from

Answer (score 1):

I used the BeanConfig class to embed the Swagger into my SpringBoot+Jersey implmentation, the code example is as follows,

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath( "/api" )
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{

    public JerseyConfig(){
       // method for embedding the Swagger
        configSwagger();
       // registers the REST resource classes
        configEndPoints();
    }

    private void configEndPoints(){
        // here register all the REST resource classes
    }

    private void configSwagger(){
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setSchemes( new String[]{ "http" } );
        beanConfig.setHost( "localhost:9001" );
        beanConfig.setBasePath( "/api" );
        beanConfig.setDescription( "REST API services for accessing the pcg application"  );
        beanConfig.setTitle( "RESTAPI" );
        beanConfig.setVersion( "1.0.1" );
        // this will tell Swagger config to scan only these packages
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage( "com.aig.rest.web" );
        beanConfig.setScan( true );     

        register( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class );
        register( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class );

    }

}
```

Comment: I have added this code but it doesn't seem working. I got some unrelated API on the swagger-ui page such as: "basic-error-controller, endpoint-mvc-adapter : Endpoint Mvc Adapter, environment-mvc-endpoint : Environment Mvc Endpoint". They are not from my API. It seems that swagger didn't scan my resource package. I have added the screenshot of this page in my post

Comment: Your initiating BeanConfig at the configuration level, i.e after initializing the server. Instead of that add swagger configuration while registering the REST api

Comment: I added it in the jersey resource configuration constructor. Is there a wrong place to add?

Comment: Its a correct way to add it,and can you post some more info like ResourceConfig and project structure

Comment: I have posted my jersey implementation class which extends from ResourceConfig.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `@EnableSwagger2` annotation works if the endpoints are implemented using Spring MVC instead of Jersey (or any other JAX-RS impl).

I have detailed how to accomplish this in a blog post I created earlier this year, [Microservices using Spring Boot, Jersey Swagger and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/04/05/Microservices-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-Swagger-and-Docker.html)

Basically if you need to document your Jersey-implemented endpoints via Swagger, you would need to:

1)
Make sure your Spring Boot app scans for components located in specific packages (ie com.asimio.jerseyexample.config) via:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {
        "com.asimio.jerseyexample.config", "com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest"
    }
)
```

2) Jersey configuration class implementation:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.config;
...
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.jersey.application-path:/}")
    private String apiPath;

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // Register endpoints, providers, ...
        this.registerEndpoints();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Register components where DI is needed
        this.configureSwagger();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        this.register(HelloResource.class);
        // Access through /<Jersey's servlet path>/application.wadl
        this.register(WadlResource.class);
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        // Available at localhost:port/swagger.json
        this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
        this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

        BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        config.setConfigId("springboot-jersey-swagger-docker-example");
        config.setTitle("Spring Boot + Jersey + Swagger + Docker Example");
        config.setVersion("v1");
        config.setContact("Orlando L Otero");
        config.setSchemes(new String[] { "http", "https" });
        config.setBasePath(this.apiPath);
        config.setResourcePackage("com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1");
        config.setPrettyPrint(true);
        config.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

3) Resource implementation using JAX-RS (Jersey) and Swagger annotations:

```
package com.asimio.jerseyexample.rest.v1;
...
@Component
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "Hello resource", produces = "application/json")
public class HelloResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloResource.class);

    @GET
    @Path("v1/hello/{name}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets a hello resource. Version 1 - (version in URL)", response = Hello.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Hello resource found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Hello resource not found")
    })
    public Response getHelloVersionInUrl(@ApiParam @PathParam("name") String name) {
        LOGGER.info("getHelloVersionInUrl() v1");
        return this.getHello(name, "Version 1 - passed in URL");
    }
...
}
```

4) Make sure your app's Spring Boot configuration file makes a distinction between Spring MVC (for actuator endpoints) and Jersey (for resources) endpoints:

**application.yml**

```
...
# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet path. Needs to be different than Jersey's to enable/disable Actuator endpoints access (/info, /health, ...)
server.servlet-path: /
# Jersey dispatcher servlet
spring.jersey.application-path: /api
...
```